# Hog features with square images

Tags: input, size, scikit-image

I used `skimage.feature.hog` to make my own HOG classifier(python).

```
from skimage.feature import hog

img = cv2.imread("C:\\users\\ghksk\\Desktop\\pipa_test\\positive\\face_no1000", 
                 cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

hog_feature = hog(img, 
                  orientations=9, 
                  pixels_per_cell=(8, 8), 
                  cells_per_block=(2, 2), 
                  block_norm='L2-Hys', 
                  visualize=False)

print(hog_feature.shape)
```

The input image is 64*64 pixels. And I get error below.

> C:\Users\ghksk\Anaconda3\envs\cv\lib\site-packages\skimage\feature_hog.py in 
>   hog(image, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm, visualize, visualise, transform_sqrt, feature_vector, multichannel)
>
> n_blocks_col = (n_cells_col - b_col) + 1
>   normalized_blocks = np.zeros((n_blocks_row, n_blocks_col, b_row, b_col, orientations))
>
> for r in range(n_blocks_row):
>
> ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Can you let me know what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry pixels_per_cell is not (6,6) but (8,8) & cells_per_bolck is not(1,1) but (2,2)

Comment: I run your (edited) code and didn't get any  error. The output was `(1764,)`.

Comment: Can you share the image that is giving you problems?